# crystal report viewer is not showing same layout of the report as Report opened in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

**Crystal Report Viewer Version**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

Crystal Reports 2008 version CR Developer ,Version: 12.0.0.549

**Report in Crystal Report**

[image]

**Report opened in Crystal Report Viewer**

[image]

Why the Report opened in crystal report viewer v13 is not showing same layout as Report opened in crystal reports 2008 v 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it was a bug in crystal report 13.0.0.4
i un installed the Latest version 13.0.4 and installed the old version 13.0.0.1  and now it is showing the correct formatting.